# uncaught typeerror on calling $.load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

I am constructing a page from a JSON using javascript. I am trying to follow a OOJS in building the page.

How I am getting the JSON : I am using RESTful api to get the JSON.

Once I get the JSON I am using jquery to convert it into a json object and then use the OOJS objects to convert them into the page content.

I am loading facets on the left hand side and results on the right hand side. When I click on the link of the left the complete page should refresh. I am using the results and facets objects to create the page.

Now I am facing problem in calling the loadPage(callbackurl). I am getting a JS error

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

Have attached the files below. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks in advance

HTML Page :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>  
            <title></title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <link href="assets/css/faceted-search.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="js/mcu.json"></script>
            <script src="js/facets.js"></script>
            <script src="js/results.js"></script>
            <script src="js/tags.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            <script>
                function getUrlVars()
                {
                    var vars = [], hash;
                    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
                    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
                    {
                        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                        vars.push(hash[0]);
                        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
                    }
                    return vars;
                }
            </script>

            <script>
                // Get the values from the query string
                    var results;
                    var facets;
                    function loadPage(callbackurl){
                    var query = getUrlVars()["query"];
                    $("#hidecontent").load(callbackurl, function(response, status, xhr){
                        query = query.replace("%20", " ");
                        $('input#inputsearch').val(query);
                        //var mcu = response;
                        jsonObj = $.parseJSON(response);
                        results = new results(jsonObj);
                        results.createResults("results");

                    $('div#facets').find('div.content').find('div.topDiv').find('div').find('a').click(function(e){
                            console.log(e);
                            var facetsDiv = $('div#facets').find('div.content');
                            var querystring = 'rest/nxp-facetSearch?query=' + $('input#inputsearch').val() + '&facet='  + $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id')+ "~" + $(this).attr('id') ;
                            loadPage(querystring);

                            $.each(facetsDiv, function(){
                                    // If length of the selector > 0 then true else false
                                    var selectedfacetvalues = $(this).find('a.selected');
                                    var selectedstring = "";
                                    if(selectedfacetvalues.length){
                                        $.each(selectedfacetvalues, function(){
                                            selectedstring = selectedstring + $(this).attr('id') + ",";
                                        });
                                        querystring = querystring + $(this).attr('id') + "~" + selectedstring.slice(0, -1) + ";";
                                    }

                            });
                            console.log(querystring);
                        });                    
                    });


                }


            </script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div id="hidecontent" style="display: none">

        </div>
        <div id="topheader">
            <img src="images/NXP_logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="framecontent">
            <div id="facets" class="innertube">
                <div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="searchbox">
            <input id="inputsearch" type="text" value="" size="40" />&nbsp; <img class="searchimg" src="images/Search.png" style="cursor: pointer" />
        </div>
        <!--div id="tags">

        </div-->
        <div id="maincontent">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <div id="results">

                </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var query = getUrlVars()["query"];

            callbackurl = "rest/nxp-facetSearch?query=" + query + "";
            loadPage(callbackurl);
        </script>



    </body>
    </html>
```

JSON file :

Please let me know if I need to attach the json file too.

Result.js :

```
    /* 
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    var localObject;

    function results(){

    }

    function results(jsonObject){
        localObject = jsonObject;
    }

    results.prototype.createResults = function(targetID){
        resultsDiv = document.getElementById(targetID);
        resultsDiv.innerHTML = "";
        container = document.createElement("div");
        container.setAttribute("id", "container");
        resultsDiv.appendChild(container);
        var values = localObject.results;
        if(values.length > 0){
            results.createTable(resultsDiv, values);
        }else{
            var noresults = document.createElement("span");
            noresults.innerHTML = "No results found!";
            resultsDiv.appendChild(noresults);
        }
    }

    results.prototype.createTable = function(resultsDiv, values){
        var topdiv = document.createElement("div");
        //table.setAttribute("class", "products");
        for (var v in values)
        {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var span = document.createElement("span");
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            span.setAttribute("class", values[v].type);
            div.setAttribute("class", "column");
            p.setAttribute("class", "resultcolumnvalue");
            p.innerHTML = values[v].value ;
            div.appendChild(span);
            div.appendChild(p);

            topdiv.appendChild(div);
        }
        resultsDiv.appendChild(topdiv);
    }
```

Comment: It would help to also let us know on what line did the error occur?

Comment: do you get the result for this line:: var query = getUrlVars()["query"]; ...?

Comment: import `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` before other plugins and custom js files.